# how to completely uninstall AirBeam TV?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, appletv, driver, macos

I installed AirBeam TV for streaming to a non-Apple TV device.

I have now uninstalled it but somehow the audio driver is still installed when I check the sound setting. It is annoying that very often I have to go and change the setting to 'Internal Speaker' as it keeps defaulting back to AirBeam TV.

Is there a way I can manually delete this. Note that to Audio Driver for this streaming app was downloaded separately and I just clicked to run it. It has somehow installed into a directory which I do not know how to navigate.

Answer (score 3):

From https://www.airbeam.tv/faqwd/how-can-i-uninstall-the-airbeamtv-audio-driver-2/

> First, find out what driver version(s) you have installed. Go to
> System Preferences -> Sound -> select the Output tab. Look at the list
> of the sound output devices.
>
> If you see “AirBeamTV Audio”, you have
> the audio driver version 2. To uninstall it, you need to delete
> /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/AirBeamTVAudio.driver
>
> Detailed instructions:
>
> 1. Open Finder
> 2. Use the menu “Go” -> “Go to folder…” (or press Shift + Command + G)
> 3. Copy the following path: /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL
> 4. Click “Go”
> 5. Delete “AirBeamTVAudio.driver”. You will need to enter the administrator password because this is a system location
> 6. Reboot your computer. After the reboot the driver will disappear in the system sound preferences
>
> If you see “AirBeamTV”, you still have the audio driver version 1. To
> uninstall it, you need to delete /Library/Extensions/AirBeamTV.kext
>
> Detailed instructions:
>
> 1. Open Finder
> 2. Use the menu “Go” -> “Go to folder…” (or press Shift + Command + G)
> 3. Copy the following path: /Library/Extensions
> 4. Click “Go”
> 5. Delete “AirBeamTV.kext”. You will need to enter the administrator password because this is a system location
> 6. Reboot your computer. After the reboot the driver will disappear in the system sound preferences

Comment: I am on High Sierra , and I cannot spot AirBeamTV.kext even though it shows up in the preferences > Sound on my mac

Answer (score 1):

On macOS Catalina (10.15) and above, the folder is located in  /System/Volumes/Data/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL